# Command doesn't work in script, but works in shell

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ubuntu, ssh

I'm writing a script for using SSH "profiles", **~/scripts/ssh-profiled.sh**

```
PROFILE=`cat ~/script/ssh-profiles/$1`
echo [ssh $PROFILE]
ssh $PROFILE
```

**~/scripts/ssh-profiles/tummi**

```
-i ~/Dropbox/security/key-nopass/key-nopass.pvt bart@example.com
```

When I run the script, it fails:

```
bart@bart-laptop:~$ script/ssh-profiled.sh tummi
[ssh -i ~/Dropbox/security/key-nopass/key-nopass.pvt bart@example.com]
Warning: Identity file ~/Dropbox/security/key-nopass/key-nopass.pvt not accessible: No such file or directory.
bart@example.com's password:
```

But this works:

```
bart@bart-laptop:~$ ssh -i ~/Dropbox/security/key-nopass/key-nopass.pvt bart@example.com
Linux tummi 2.6.32-24-server #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 06:21:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS

Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
```

Is there an error/gotcha in my script?

Comment: As an experiment, add `echo ~` to the script somewhere.

Comment: Any experiment is useful to try, but that one will just get you more confused as you'll see ~ expanded to the home directory but the expansion still will not work for ssh. See Victor's answer with "eval" for why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change 1st line to

```
eval PROFILE=`cat ~/script/ssh-profiles/$1`
```

For explanation see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)

Comment: Beat me to it. An alternative is "eval ssh $PROFILE" which is how I was going to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The ~ in your file needs to be the full home directory path, it's not getting expanded.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the "~/" is not being interpreted as expected when passed in that way. Try using an explicit full path.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the .pvt file? If only you have read access, and no one can execute it, then your script might not be able to even see the file. That could be why you are getting the `"...not accessible: No such file or directory."` message.

Comment: "No such file or directory" (ENOENT) is not a permission error (EACCES).